# How do I set NSUserDefault settings as Instance Variables?

Tags: swift, nsuserdefaults, instance-variables

When I try to just set a constant based on the settings like below, it results in Optional("value").

```
let accesstoken = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().stringForKey("accessToken")
let userId = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().stringForKey("userId")
```

If I do it like the below, I get an error saying variable used within its own initial value. I can't seem to win here. What am I doing wrong?

```
var accesstoken = String()
var userId = Int()


if let atString = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().stringForKey("accessToken") {
    accesstoken = atString
}

if let userIdString = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().stringForKey("userId") {
    userId = userIdString
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve what you want with a read only computed property combined with the [nil coalescing operator](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/BasicOperators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH6-ID72) "??". Try like this:

```
var accessToken: String {
    return NSUserDefaults().stringForKey("accessToken") ?? ""
}

var userId: String {
    return NSUserDefaults().stringForKey("userId") ?? ""
}
```

or if you need an Int for your userID

```
var userId: Int {
    return NSUserDefaults().integerForKey("userId")
}
```

Comment: What does the ?? "" part at the end do?

Comment: it checks if the key has a value and if there is no value instead of returning nil you can define a default value for the key

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/BasicOperators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH6-ID72